# Take column pair values and build object

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I have quite a complex Postgres query at the minute, and it returns records as follows:

```
-[ RECORD 1 ]-------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
e_id                | 10
s_ids               | ["252", "250", "254", "255", "253", "249", "251"]
properties          | {"text": "This is some random example text filling it out", "f_id": "1"}
breakdown           | ["This is some", "is some random", "some random example", "random example text", "example text filling", "text filling it", "filling it out"]
score               | ["469.954", "421.158", "402.728", "378.867", "411.911", "371.425", "459.896"]
```

As you can see, the columns `s_ids`, `breakdown` and `score` all have 7 values separated by ---

I want to try and return one column, as opposed to these 3, and have that column become an array of objects instead, the column would look something like this:

```
[{"breakdown": "This is some", "score": 469.954, "s_id": 252},{"breakdown": "is some random", "score": 421.158, "s_id": 250},etc...]
```

As a result of my underlying query being complex, I am struggling to do this. I've tried playing with jsonb_build_object but I get `GROUP BY` issues every time.

My actual query looks something like this:

```
select m.eid as e_id,
        json_agg(s_id::text) as s_ids,
        e.properties as properties,
        json_agg(array_to_string((regexp_split_to_array(e.properties || (substring(m.position->'position'->>'path' from 'properties(.+)\)')),'\s+'))[(m.position->'position'->>'start')::integer + 1:(m.position->'position'->>'end')::integer + 1],' ')) as breakdown,
        json_agg((distance_func(o_e,(select * from cte1)))::text) as score
    from cte2 a
    inner join table1 m on a.s_id = m.id
    inner join table2 e on e.id = m.e_id
    group by 1, 3
```

I'm just looking for a push in the right direction in terms of what I should look at doing for this issue. The m.position referenced in will also occur as many times as s_ids, etc, but I don't need this field returned.

Comment: Never ever put multiple values in a single field. And if you do, use at least an array of json, these are made for things like that.

Comment: Thanks for that, I'll update my question accordingly

Comment: It would be easier if you showed us the original content of the `properties` and `position` columns before you take them apart. Applying `string_to_array` on a JSON column seems rather dubious anyway. A [dbFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13)  with some more sample data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, what you want to do is construct a JSON object for each "breakdown" and "score" and then aggregate into an array.  The pseudo-code is:

```
json_agg( json_build_object('breakdown', breakdown, 'score', score) )
```

I don't follow the logic of your query.  It doesn't produce the same columns as your sample data.  Both `breakdown` and `score` can be expressions.